# How to iterate over the string using data weave 1.0 and data weave 2.0?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I'm new to dataweave and trying to transform the array and iterate over the "||" values

Input:

```
[
    {
        "card":"VISA$$0.0||MASTER$$140.0"
    },
    {
        "card":"VISA$$0.0||MASTER$$147.0"
    }
]
```

The DataWeave code that I tried:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"CardList":payload map (data,index) ->
{
    (data.card splitBy "||" map {
        "sur": $
    })
}
```

Expected response :

```
{
  "cardList": [

        {
          "card": "VISA$$0.0"
        },
        {
          "card": "MASTER$$140.0"
        },
        {
          "card": "VISA$$0.0"
        },
        {
          "card": "MASTER$$147.0"
        }
  ]
}
```

Someone one could you please assist me here on mule 3 and 4.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ask this as two separate questions for mule 3 and mule 4.

Comment: This question is not really about 'iterating' over the data. Instead is about how to split the string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below - iterating through splitBy values (||)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"CardList": flatten(payload map 
( ($.card splitBy  "||")  map(item,index) -> 
{
    card : item
}))
```

Comment: You could alternatively use flatMap() instead of combining flatten() and map().